# ClaimsAuthorizationManager pull policies from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authorization, .net-4.5, claims-based-identity

I'm new to the Claims Security approach for authorizing users access to resources.  I've been doing a lot of research and the majority of sites I've read have the policies for ClaimsAuthorizationManager entered in Web.config file.  What are some ways to accomplish this?  Can you point me to some links where policies are served from a database?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into the same problem. Hopefully these links will help you. What I did was implemented my own `ClaimsAuthorizationManager` to get the claims for the current user and used [Thinktecture.IdentityModel](http://identitymodel.codeplex.com/) for claims checks.

[http://www.codeproject.com/Claims-Based-Authentication-and-Authorization](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/639458/Claims-Based-Authentication-and-Authorization)

http://evolvingtechie.wordpress.com/misc/identity-and-access-management/claims-authorization-in-geneva-beta-2-%E2%80%93-introduction/

http://www.contentmaster.com/windows-communication-foundation/implementing-customizable-claims-based-authorization-with-windows-identity-foundation/

This has some snippets you can use.
https://github.com/maniserowicz/claims-talk/tree/master/Claims.WG.NET/_snippets