# ClaimsAuthorizationManager database configuration

Tags: authorization, .net-4.5, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I followed the MSDN post on implementing a claim-based authorization. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsauthorizationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx

It uses XML configuration in Web.config to define policies.

1. Can the policies be stored and pulled from database instead of file?
2. If not, can this be done in another file?

> LoadCustomConfiguration   - When overridden in a derived class, loads
>   custom configuration from XML.

[ClaimsAuthorizationManager pull policies from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18029871/claimsauthorizationmanager-pull-policies-from-database) is the same question but contains **no answer for database implementation** or reading it from another xml file other than web.config.

Comment: Just found the solution myself. 1. Implement LoadCustomConfiguration - make sure config file is using the new customManager. 2. <policy file="Policy.xml" /> - Add a dummy policy.xml so that it runs into the loadCustomConfiguration code. 3. Load the database configuration and put that in the policy dictionary as the Microsoft example did.

Comment: I am running into the same issue... we want to be able to modify the policy on the fly which would require it to be in the database.  Can you give any details on your solution?  What specifically did you do in the LoadCustomConfiguration method, what does the database look like to store the policies. etc...